# Manipulating matrices obtained by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, function-construction

For example,
Matrix U is obtained by

```
U[w1_, w2_, w3_]:= NDSolveValue[
        {u'[t] == - I H[w1, w2, w3, t] . u[t], u[0] == IdentityMatrix[3]},
        u,
        {t, 0, 2 Pi}
    ]
```

where

```
H[w1_, w2_, w3_, t_] := {
        {0, Cos[w1 t], Cos[w3 t]},
        {Cos[w1 t], 0, Cos[w2 t]},
        {Cos[w3 t], Cos[w2 t], 0}
    }
```

then a function defined of U[w1,w2,w3][t] would be like:

```
f[w1_, w2_, w3_, t_] := Tr[U[w1, w2, w3][t] .
   {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 0}} .
   ConjugateTranspose[U[w1, w2, w3][t]]]
```

**When I want to do** `NFourierTransform[f[1, 2, 3, t], t, \[Omega]]`

the outcome is just[image]

which is not what I am expecting

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: An actual use case that does not work for you would be helpful. For instance `f[1, 2, 3, 4]` seems to work fine for me. A better way to define `U` (iimho) is `U = ParametricNDSolveValue[{u'[t] == -I H[w1, w2, w3, t] . u[t], u[0] == IdentityMatrix[3]}, u, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {w1, w2, w3}]`.  `ParametricNDSolve` was built to handle such things and has certain efficiencies built in.

Comment: Question have been edited. I want to do something of f[w1,w2,w3,t] rather than just get the outcome of f[w1,w2,w3,t].

Comment: (1) `NFourierTransform[func, t, w]` does not evaluate unless `w` is numeric. (2) The Fourier transform is an integral over the whole real line, but your function `ff` is not defined over the whole real line. Did you intend the Fourier series?

Comment: @Micheal E2 Getting the Fourier series is also great. It is an effective way to do that?